# Can you add a loading (not a menu background) image or video to grub?

Tags: linux, grub, bootloader

When you boot out of the box ubuntu, there is a post grub menu "animation" of orange circles loading. I want to know if I can instruct grub to display my own custom image during the post menu bootloading. I have tried looking this up,m but I only get how to change the background.

My main OS is arch linux btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package that handles the boot screen is called plymouth. Grub’s job ends as soon as an operating system is selected (either by user input or timeout).

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/2009) gives some details on how to change the Plymouth theme.